# Constructor returns unexpected null

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

java beginner here!

I want an object Model that is a list of random coordinates, and according to (*) the ArrayList is not empty when the the main runs Model(200). But when I run main I get an out of bounds error when I test with the printout around (**) I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Is the problem with the constructor Model?

```
public class Model extends ArrayList<Particle>{ 
private ArrayList<Particle> particleList;

public Model(int N) {
    ArrayList<Particle> list1 = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    Particle newParticle = new Particle(); 
    for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
        list1.add(newParticle);
        newParticle = new Particle();
        //String s= String.valueOf(newParticle.x);
        //System.out.println(s);
        }
    this.particleList = list1;
    Particle p1 = particleList.get(5);
    double d = p1.x;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println(s);                            (*)
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Model x1 = new Model(200);
    Particle p1 = x1.get(0);                           (**)
    double d = p1.x;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: I believe you are not calling your ``paricleList`` variable with ``x1.get(0)`` but the element from the superclass (you extended ArrayList). If you want to get elements from ``particleList`` you should define a getter, then do something like: ``x1.getParticleList().get(0)``.

Comment: do you really want to extend an ArrayList?

Comment: Can you expand @BalajiKrishnan? I did it because I wanted to use .get(i), but maybe I should use Plebejusz tip instead. Why wouldn't I want to extend ArrayList?

Comment: yes. user Model<Particle> and create a getter for particleList

Comment: have added an answer to elaborate what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the array that Model actually IS because of the fact that it extends from ArrayList, and an ArrayList that your Model CONTAINS.

If you want your Model to be an ArrayList, you don't need that particleList property. You could do this:

```
public class Model extends ArrayList<Particle> { 

  public Model(int N) {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          Particle newParticle = new Particle();
          this.add(newParticle);
      }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Model x1 = new Model(200);
    Particle p1 = x1.get(0);                           (**)
    double d = p1.x;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Model class is already an ArrayList. Your particleList field is useless.

Try this :

```
public class Model extends ArrayList<Particle>{ 


public Model(int N) {

    for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
        this.add(new Particle());

    Particle p1 = this.get(5);
    double d = p1.x;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println(s);                            (*)
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Model x1 = new Model(200);
    Particle p1 = x1.get(0);                           (**)
    double d = p1.x;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop that creating a list of `Particle`, I think this will solve the problem:

```
list1.add(new Particle());
```

And remove the line that instantiate the `Particle` object outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no need to extend ArrayList (no new functionality is being added). The below should work fine

```
public class Model {
    private List<Particle> particleList = null;

    public Model(int count) {
        particleList = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            particleList.add(new Particle());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model x1 = new Model(300);
        Particle p = x1. getParticleList().get(0);
        System.out.println(p.x);
       //using the new method - no need to extend ArrayList
        System.out.print(x1.get(3));

    }

    //rather than extending Arraylist, you can create a new method and use get(index) like this one:
    public Particle get(int index){
        return this.getParticleList().get(index);
    }

    public List<Particle> getParticleList() {
        return particleList;
    }

    public void setParticleList(List<Particle> particleList) {
        this.particleList = particleList;
    }

}
```